# jquerymobile click event doesn't work

Tags: jquery, events, jquery-mobile, click

I'm new to JqueryMobile. I wanted to try a simple click event on a button, but it doesn't work (I'm using it in firefox)

The HTML is

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html dir='ltr'>
<head>
<title>Test Page</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/style.css"/>
<script src='js/jquery.mobile.js'></script>
<script src='js/script.js'></script>
</head>
<body> 
    <div data-role="page" id='mypage'>  
        <button id='load_ajax'>Carica</button>
        <br />
        <div id='content'></div>
    </div><!-- /content -->
</body>
</html>
```

and the script in script.js is

```
$('#mypage').delegate('#load_ajax','click',function (e) {
    alert('test'); 
});
```

Even using the debugger, no alert pop up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose that the problem is that the selected elements do not exist on the page at the time your code makes the call to .delegate(). Furthermore please check that the JS files are properly loaded.

The below code which includes the code that you posted works properly:

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
    <head> 
        <title>Page Title</title> 
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.1.1/jquery.mobile-1.1.1.min.css" />
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.1.1/jquery.mobile-1.1.1.min.js"></script>
    </head> 
    <body>
        <!-- /page -->
        <div data-role="page" id='mypage'>  
            <div id='content'>
                <button id='load_ajax'>Carica</button>
            </div>
        </div>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $('#mypage').delegate('#load_ajax','click', function (e) {
                alert('test'); 
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Furthermore as mentioned in the jQuery API:

> As of jQuery 1.7, .delegate() has been superseded by the .on() method. For earlier versions, however, it remains the most effective means to use event delegation.
>
> *Event handlers are bound only to the **currently selected elements** and **they must exist on the page at the time your code makes the call** to .on()*. To ensure the elements are present and can be selected, ***perform event binding inside a document ready handler*** for elements that are in the HTML markup on the page. If new HTML is being injected into the page, select the elements and attach event handlers ***after the new HTML is placed into the page***. Or, ***use delegated events*** to attach an event handler.
>
> Delegated events have the advantage that they can process events from descendant elements that are added to the document at a later time. By picking an element that is guaranteed to be present at the time the delegated event handler is attached, you can use delegated events to avoid the need to frequently attach and remove event handlers. This element could be the container element of a view in a Model-View-Controller design, for example, or document if the event handler wants to monitor all bubbling events in the document. **The document element is available in the head of the document before loading any other HTML, so it is safe to attach events there without waiting for the document to be ready**.

Having read the above you may consider changing your code to:

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
    <head> 
        <title>Page Title</title> 
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.1.1/jquery.mobile-1.1.1.min.css" />
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.1.1/jquery.mobile-1.1.1.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).on('click', '#load_ajax', function(e){
                // your code
                alert($(this).text());
            });
        </script>
    </head> 
    <body>
        <!-- /page -->
        <div data-role="page" id='mypage'>  
            <div id='content'>
                <button id='load_ajax'>Carica</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I think this solution works because it calls jquery-1.7.2. If you remove that library it doesn't work anymore.
Is this necessary? I thought jquerymobile didn't need jquery.

Comment: You may read the http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.2.0/docs/about/getting-started.html and check the http://jquerymobile.com/download/. If you remove jQuery then the $ symbol cannot be resolved in the jQuery Mobile JS file.